# Highlight Two Textviews on one touch

Tags: android, textview, highlight

I've got two textviews that use a 'selector' resource as a background so they change colour when the user is touching it.  However, I want to make it so that when the user touches one of the textviews, both the textviews highlight.  How would I do this?

The textviews are in separate linear layouts.

Answer (score 2):

Combine them into one layout and set layout to clickable.
Also, set the "Duplicate Parent State" of two textviews to true.

Comment: Is there another way to do it?  The two textviews are in separate layouts and it would be very hard to get the positioning right if I put them in the same layout.

Comment: You can use the event to change the other view parameters.

Comment: I've tried textview2.performClick() when the textview1 gets clicked but this doesn't highlight textview2.  I've looked through the methods for textview and I don't see one where I can set the state.

Comment: It is hard to control the state of a view. The easiest way is to listen the state of current view and control the other view.